# Wordpress REST API solo muestra 10 resultados

Tags: wordpress

tengo el siguiente código en un PHP (podcast.php) para traerme información del REST API en la raíz de Wordpress.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);
$uri = 'http://sitio.local/wp-json/wp/v2/podcast/';

$json = file_get_contents($uri,false, $context);

$posts= json_decode($json);

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "<li><a href='" . $post->link . "'>" . $post->title->rendered . "</a></li>\n";
}
```

Accedo desde el navegador
http://sitio.local/podcast

Y el problema que tengo es que solo me muestra 10 resultados cuando hay más de 100.

Podcast esta creado mediante Custom Post Type y activada la opción para ver en REST API

En el Disable REST API tengo marcadas estas opciones

```
 /wp/v2/podcast
 /wp/v2/podcast/(?P<id>[\d]+)
 /wp/v2/podcast/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions
 /wp/v2/podcast/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/revisions/(?P<id>[\d]+)
 /wp/v2/podcast/(?P<id>[\d]+)/autosaves
 /wp/v2/podcast/(?P<parent>[\d]+)/autosaves/(?P<id>[\d]+)
```

¿Alguna idea porque no me muestra todos los resultados?

Comment: probá con el parámetro [`?per_page=`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) o [modificando el query rest del cpt](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_this-post_type_query/)

Comment: Ok lo probare, muchas gracias